# How do I build a website that has the same resolution as my 8th gen iPad?

Tags: ipad, screen-resolution

The resolution of my iPad 8 is 2160x1620. When I build a website with a div that is 1000 pixels wide, that div is nearly 90% wide on my iPad's screen. That is not what I expected.

On my iMac (full HD) the div is displayed with the correct width. How can I solve this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
</head> 
    <body>
        <div style="width: 1000px; background-color: aqua; height: 10px"></div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this in the `<head>` portion of your page:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This should make your document scale correctly with your device's screen resolution.

You can read more about how it works on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).

Comment: I tried exactly what you suggested but my ipad still shows the same width of the div. I edited my example code.

Comment: @PeterKarlsson Are you using safari?

Comment: Yes I am and I honestly hate it. Maybe I should use firefox?

Comment: @PeterKarlsson Well, you should check it out in FF, just to make sure that the issue is specific to Safari. If your project is personal—then use what you prefer and don't bother fixing the issue, if it only shows up in safari. If you are making a public website, then you'll have to fix it anyway :D But first—check if it works in FF, please. I heard of some bugs with safari's treatment of viewports, but haven't seen them myself.

Comment: I have just installed and tested Firefox. Same behavior. Strange.

Comment: I also tested Chrome. Same behavior.

Comment: @PeterKarlsson Just to be clear: setting the viewport does absolutely nothing in all browsers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226693/discussion-between-peter-karlsson-and-jklen).